# Proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \cos^{2n}(2\pi x) = \mathbf{1}_{\left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I gave myself a little project to show that the sequence of even powers of $\cos$ converges to a spike-train.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \cos^{2n}(2\pi x) = \mathbf{1}_{\left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}(x)$$

I'd like to ensure that the following is a legitimate proof.

$$0 \leq \cos^{2n}(2\pi x)\leq|\cos(2\pi x)| < 1 \;\forall m \in \mathbb{N^+},x \notin \left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

$$ 0 \leq c < 1 \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} c^n = 0 \implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \cos^{2n}(2\pi x) = 0,\; \forall x \notin \left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

$$ \exists k \in \mathbb{N^+}: \cos^{2k}(2\pi x)= 1,  \implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \cos^{2(k+n)}(2\pi x) = 1,\; \forall x \in \left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

$$\cos^{2}(2\pi x) = 1 \;\forall x \in \left\{\frac{m}{2},m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

$\square$

Comment: Convergence of a sequence of distributions $\Lambda_n$ to a distribution $\Lambda$ requires convergence of $\Lambda_n(\phi)$ to $\Lambda(\phi)$ for all test functions $\phi\in \mathscr{D}$.  Rudin *Functional Analysis* 6.16.

Comment: Surely you don't mean the Dirac train with infinitely tall spikes?

Comment: In your question as originally posed you spoke of a Dirac train, which is why I brought up distributions.  The Dirac $\delta$ is still in your title.

Comment: @ForgotALot yes, my mistake...I can't correct right now but I will modify the title.

Comment: In answer to your question, yes the proof is valid, but it could be simplified: If $2x \notin \Bbb N, \cos^2 2\pi x = c < 1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n} 2\pi x =\lim_{n\to\infty} c^n = 0$. if $2x \in \Bbb N$, then $\cos^2 2\pi x = 1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n} 2\pi x = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n = 1$. 'Nuff said.

Comment: @PaulSinclair many thanks! Yes your approach is much more straightforward.

Comment: It's the same proof, of course. I just pulled out what was necessary and stated it more clearly.

Comment: @ForgotALot ok...title now matches post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Sinclair provided a nice abridged and better organized version of my proof. I reproduce it here so I can close out this question:

$$2x \notin \Bbb N \implies \cos^2 2\pi x = c < 1 \implies\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n} 2\pi x =\lim_{n\to\infty} c^n = 0$$

$$2x \in \Bbb N \implies \cos^2 2\pi x = 1 \implies\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n} 2\pi x =\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n = 1$$

$\square$